# frame.getContentPane().add(); not working properly?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've been having some (very annoying) trouble with these scripts that I've created.

Sburb.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Sburb
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Welcome to Sburb");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    spirograph page = new spirograph();
    progressbar bar = new progressbar();

    frame.getContentPane().add(page);
    frame.getContentPane().add(bar);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    }
}
```

progressbar.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*; 

public class progressbar extends JPanel
{

JProgressBar current;
JTextArea out;
JButton find;
Thread runner;
int num = 1;

progressbar() 
{
    super();

    //setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    current = new JProgressBar(0, 2000);
    current.setStringPainted(false);
    pane.add(current);
    //setContentPane(pane);
}


public void iterate() {
    while (num < 2000) {
        current.setValue(num);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        num += 5;
    }
}

//    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
//        progressbar frame = new progressbar();
//        frame.pack();
//        frame.setVisible(true);
//        frame.iterate();
//   }
}
```

spirograph.java

```
import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;


import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class spirograph extends JPanel
{
private ImageIcon image;
private JLabel label;
private JLabel frame = new JLabel();
private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

 spirograph() 
{

    this.setOpaque(true);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Gate.gif"));
    label = new JLabel(image);
    add(label);

    progressbar bar = new progressbar();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call the file "progressbar" to the Sburb file but when I do, it gives me just the simple JFrame of this (not fixed):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHZTl.jpg

And when I get rid of the "frame.getContentPane().add(bar);" in Sburb.java, it gives me this (fixed, kind-of):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brmke.jpg

How do I fix this? I've looked everywhere and yet I still can't figure it out! I also can't seem to figure out how to align the bar directly below the gif.

Answer (score 4):

```
frame.getContentPane().add(page);
frame.getContentPane().add(bar);
```

The content pane of a `JFrame` is a set to a `BorderLayout` which can only accept *one component* in any *one* of the border layout constraints.  Given no constraints were supplied here, the JRE will try to put them both in the `CENTER`.

For this, and a variety of other reasons, I would advise to ignore the existing content pane, arrange the entire GUI (as many panels as it consists of) into another panel (let's call it `ui`) then call

```
frame.setContentPane(ui);
```

Comment: Would that mean I would have to make another JPanel file and have that file call the content? I'm still a bit new to the Jframe's and JPanel's.

Comment: *"make another JPanel file and have that file call the content"*  First of all,stop extending `JPanel` when no functionality is being changed or added.  Once you've figured that out, neither `spirograph` nor `progressbar` needs to be a 'separate file', and all 3 panels (those two and `ui`) can simply be instance variables within the `Sburb` code.  That should make tings simpler, without any worries about references to other Java source code files.

Comment: Also please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.